# Process multiple folders in Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I have some 100 folders. Each folder contains 5 files. I have an executable that process one folder. The executable is a black box and hence it cannot be modified.I would like to process 100 folders in parallel using Apache spark so that I should be able to span a map task per folder. Can anyone give me an idea? I have came across similar questions but with Hadoop and answer was to use combineFileInputFormat and pathFilter. However, as I said, I want to use Apache spark. Any idea?